# New integer column from multiple string columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My data is spread to 3 string columns; `col 1, col 2, col 3`. The dataset has around 500k rows and more rows added once a month.

```
Row setting                     acceptance_rate    undergrads    
1   City                        N/A                2773  
2   198                         Town               77%
3   133                         Suburban           56%
4   55%                         254                Suburban  
5   54%                         Rural              46    
6   63%                         City               247   
7   100%                        210                Rural
```

I would like to create 2 new columns to group numbers for certain conditions. I want the new column `acceptance_rate_new` to have all the numbers between 0 and 1, whereas, and `population` would have numbers above 1. I thought the following `CASE ... WHEN` would be sufficient for this task since it worked for string to string but it does not work this time. I guess I would need to run the query once a month.

```
SELECT _name, COALESCE(
  CASE WHEN INTEGER(col1) > 1 THEN INTEGER(col1) ELSE NULL END, 
  CASE WHEN INTEGER(col2) > 1 THEN INTEGER(col2) ELSE NULL END, 
  CASE WHEN INTEGER(col3) > 1 THEN INTEGER(col3) ELSE NULL END
  ) AS population_new
FROM
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and "re-distributes" correct values to respective columns (versus current random distribution across columns)
Using this you can put on top whatever logic you need

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 'City' setting, 'N/A' acceptance_rate, '2773' undergrads UNION ALL
  SELECT '198', 'Town', '77%' UNION ALL
  SELECT '133', 'Suburban', '56%' UNION ALL
  SELECT '55%', '254', 'Suburban' UNION ALL
  SELECT '54%', 'Rural', '46' UNION ALL
  SELECT '63%', 'City', '247' UNION ALL
  SELECT '100%', '210', 'Rural' 
)
SELECT setting, acceptance_rate, undergrads,
  COALESCE(
    IF(setting IN (undergrads_correct, acceptance_rate_correct, 'N/A'), NULL, setting),
    IF(acceptance_rate IN (undergrads_correct, acceptance_rate_correct, 'N/A'), NULL, acceptance_rate),
    IF(undergrads IN (undergrads_correct, acceptance_rate_correct, 'N/A'), NULL, undergrads)
  ) setting_correct,
  CAST(undergrads_correct AS INT64) undergrads_correct,
  acceptance_rate_correct
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
    COALESCE(
      IF(NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(setting AS INT64)), setting, NULL),
      IF(NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(acceptance_rate AS INT64)), acceptance_rate, NULL),
      IF(NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(undergrads AS INT64)), undergrads, NULL)
    ) AS undergrads_correct,
    COALESCE(
      IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(setting, '%$') AND NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(setting, '%', '') AS INT64)), setting, NULL),
      IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(acceptance_rate, '%$') AND NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(acceptance_rate, '%', '') AS INT64)), acceptance_rate, NULL),
      IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(undergrads, '%$') AND NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(undergrads, '%', '') AS INT64)), undergrads, NULL)
    ) acceptance_rate_correct
  FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
)
```

result is

```sql
setting   acceptance_rate   undergrads  setting_correct undergrads_correct  acceptance_rate_correct  
City      N/A               2773        City                          2773  null     
63%       City              247         City                           247  63%  
198       Town              77%         Town                           198  77%  
54%       Rural             46          Rural                           46  54%  
100%      210               Rural       Rural                          210  100%     
133       Suburban          56%         Suburban                       133  56%  
55%       254               Suburban    Suburban                       254  55%
```

Below is version with use of SQL UDF (with the same output of course)

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION check_int(val STRING) AS (
  (IF(NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(val AS INT64)), val, NULL))
);
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION check_rate(val STRING) AS (
  IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(val, '%$') AND NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(val, '%', '') AS INT64)), val, NULL)
);
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION check_city(val STRUCT<setting STRING, acceptance_rate STRING, undergrads STRING, undergrads_correct STRING, acceptance_rate_correct STRING>) AS (
  COALESCE(
    IF(val.setting IN (val.undergrads_correct, val.acceptance_rate_correct, 'N/A'), NULL, val.setting),
    IF(val.acceptance_rate IN (val.undergrads_correct, val.acceptance_rate_correct, 'N/A'), NULL, val.acceptance_rate),
    IF(val.undergrads IN (val.undergrads_correct, val.acceptance_rate_correct, 'N/A'), NULL, val.undergrads)
  ) 
);
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 'City' setting, 'N/A' acceptance_rate, '2773' undergrads UNION ALL
  SELECT '198', 'Town', '77%' UNION ALL
  SELECT '133', 'Suburban', '56%' UNION ALL
  SELECT '55%', '254', 'Suburban' UNION ALL
  SELECT '54%', 'Rural', '46' UNION ALL
  SELECT '63%', 'City', '247' UNION ALL
  SELECT '100%', '210', 'Rural' 
)
SELECT setting, acceptance_rate, undergrads,
  check_city(STRUCT(setting, acceptance_rate, undergrads, undergrads_correct, acceptance_rate_correct)) setting_correct,
  CAST(undergrads_correct AS INT64) undergrads_correct,
  acceptance_rate_correct
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    COALESCE(check_int(setting),check_int(acceptance_rate),check_int(undergrads)) AS undergrads_correct,
    COALESCE(check_rate(setting),check_rate(acceptance_rate),check_rate(undergrads)) acceptance_rate_correct
  FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
)
```

> Update for - `would I manually need to enter values for each row one by one?`

You don't need to enter manually all your data - rather you should remove WITH section with all dummy data and replace yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable with your own - similar to below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT setting, acceptance_rate, undergrads,
  COALESCE(
    IF(setting IN (undergrads_correct, acceptance_rate_correct, 'N/A'), NULL, setting),
    IF(acceptance_rate IN (undergrads_correct, acceptance_rate_correct, 'N/A'), NULL, acceptance_rate),
    IF(undergrads IN (undergrads_correct, acceptance_rate_correct, 'N/A'), NULL, undergrads)
  ) setting_correct,
  CAST(undergrads_correct AS INT64) undergrads_correct,
  acceptance_rate_correct
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
    COALESCE(
      IF(NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(setting AS INT64)), setting, NULL),
      IF(NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(acceptance_rate AS INT64)), acceptance_rate, NULL),
      IF(NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(undergrads AS INT64)), undergrads, NULL)
    ) AS undergrads_correct,
    COALESCE(
      IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(setting, '%$') AND NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(setting, '%', '') AS INT64)), setting, NULL),
      IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(acceptance_rate, '%$') AND NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(acceptance_rate, '%', '') AS INT64)), acceptance_rate, NULL),
      IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(undergrads, '%$') AND NOT IS_NAN(SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(undergrads, '%', '') AS INT64)), undergrads, NULL)
    ) acceptance_rate_correct
  FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`
)
```

Comment: Hi Mikail - Thank you so much for such a comprehensive answer. This method would work for the existing rows but would I manually need to enter values for each row one by one?

Comment: @efe That's just your example data, as you didn't provide table name...

Comment: @Efe - you don't need to enter manually - this is just an example. for real run remove WITH section with all dummy data and replace `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` with your own. See update in answer.  Try & let us know